# Create SQL Server DSN with SQLConfigDataSource failed: Invalid keyword-value pairs

Tags: c++, sql-server, winapi, odbc

```
static bool DBBase::CreateDSN(const TCHAR* sDriver, const TCHAR * sCreateDsnString)
{
    if (SQLConfigDataSource(NULL, ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN, sDriver, sCreateDsnString))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        WORD wErrNum = 1;
        WORD cbRet;
        DWORD pErr;
        TCHAR szErrMsg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
        while (SQLInstallerError(wErrNum, &pErr, szErrMsg, SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, &cbRet) != SQL_NO_DATA)
        {
            _WRITELOGN(szErrMsg);
            wErrNum++;
        };
        return false;
    }
}

    void test()
{
    const TCHAR* sDriver = _T("SQL Server");
    const TCHAR* sCreateDsnString = _T("DSN=myDSN\0Server=myIP\\MyDbInstance\0Database=myDB\0Trusted_Connection=no\0UID=sa\0PWD=sa\0\0");
    DBBase::CreateDSN(sDriver, sCreateDsnString);
}
```

When `Trusted_Connection=yes` and without user id and password, it workes. But when with user id and password, it fails with error messages:

> Invalid keyword-value pairs Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or
>
> ConfigTranslator failed

I have tried "user id", "UID" and "Username" for UID field and "Password", "PWD" for password field, all failed.

Answer (score 0):

The driver just not allows storing user name and password as a part of DSN because it is not safe. So do not specify UID and PWD attributes when creating a DSN, the attributes should be specified on connection stage.